# Reading and using values from a List<string[]>?

Tags: c#, string, list, separator

I'm pretty fresh when it comes to C#, and I have run into a problem.

I was wondering how I should go about getting data from a `List<string[]>` and using it to create objects in a `List<MyClass>`?

```
class FileLoader
{
    public FileLoader()
    {
        if (File.Exists("texter.txt"))
        {
            List<string> itemSaver = new List<string>();
            List<string[]> vectors = new List<string[]>();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("texter.txt", Encoding.Default, true);
            for (string item = reader.ReadLine(); item != null; item = reader.ReadLine())
            {
                itemSaver.Add(item);
            }
            foreach (string a in itemSaver)
            {
                string[] vektor = a.Split(new string[] { "###" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                vectors.Add(vektor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The textfile has ### as separators, and I need to get the values between them, which is why the Split was done. Now I just need some help figuring out **how**..

Kind regards.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. If you want to create `MyClass` objects, why not do that in your `foreach` loop instead of creating a `List<string[]>`? Do the split, but then create a `MyClass` object from the resulting `string[]`...

Comment: "How" to do what, exactly?  Is this code not working in some way?  `vectors` should now contain the arrays of values that you put in it, no?  What are you trying to do with those values?

Comment: You seem to be wanting to create a list of objects by parsing a file line-by-line. Create each object and assign relevant data to its properties in each iteration of the loop and add the resulting object to the list.

Comment: I'm also doubt about why the code doesn't work. It should already get the job done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one for loop :

```
    class FileLoader
    {
        List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();
        public FileLoader()
        {
            if (File.Exists("texter.txt"))
            {
                List<string[]> vectors = new List<string[]>();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("texter.txt", Encoding.Default, true);
                for (string item = reader.ReadLine(); item != null; item = reader.ReadLine())
                {
                    string[] vektor = item.Split(new string[] { "###" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x=> x.Trim()).ToArray();
                    vectors.Add(vektor);

                    MyClass newClass = new MyClass();
                    myClassList.Add(newClass);
                    newClass.title = vektor[0];
                    newClass.type = vektor[1];
                }

            }
        }
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Works pretty good, but I still have a problem which is that in the textfile the data is split like this:  


`string1###string2###string3`

                                                                           I need all of the strings, and at the moment I'm only getting string1

Comment: How are you determining that you are getting only one string?  It may be the way you are pulling data from the results.

Comment: I'm looking in the Debug Output Window, by using this code: `for (int index = 0; index < vectors.Count; index++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}", vectors[index]);
}`

EDIT: I should clarify, I need string1 string2 string 3 from string1###string2###string3 but only seeing string1 per line

Comment: You are only printing one.  Try : { Debug.WriteLine("{0}", string.Join(",",vectors[index])); }

Comment: Oh, now I just feel stupid.. Thanks a whole lot bud, really appreciate it.

Comment: One last question; How would I go about adding these values to a new object of a class? Lets say MyClass.title = string1; MyClass.type = string2; etc?

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. Last thing I need to figure out now is how to send text to a textBox.. I can get `MessageBox.Show(books[number].ToString` working, but for some reason textboxes won't work.

Comment: What type of application are you using?  A textbox is part of a Form Applciation and you need the instance of the form to write a message to the textbox.  So the class needs 'this' from the form.  Something like this : 
In form :Form1 form1 = this (the instance);  Then pass form1 to FileLoader Class.  public FileLoader(Form1 form1){ the constructor}

Answer (score 0):

To access an existing member of vectors you use the standard [] notation for arrays, i.e.

```
string [] vector = vectors[7];
```

You don't need to assign it to a variable of course you should be able to do

```
WriteLine ("{0}", vectors[7]);
```